# Changing iPhone's date and time

Tags: ios, settings, iphone-privateapi

I'm toying with iOS SDK, and I'm trying to change the device's date and time programmatically.
I read that it's not possible with the standard SDK, which makes sense, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do so with the private APIs, as I'm just doing an app as a study, and do not intend to publish it on the App Store

Comment: AFAIK the iPhone will always sync time to the carrier.  Perhaps I'm wrong though.

Comment: It's an option which can be turned off.

Answer (score 8):

1) Add to your app entitlements `com.apple.timed` key with bool value set to `YES`

2) Disable automatic time setting (and timezone if you want)

Link to private `CoreTime.framework`. Declare these functions

```
void TMSetAutomaticTimeEnabled(BOOL);
void TMSetAutomaticTimeZoneEnabled(BOOL);
```

Disable automatic time setting

```
TMSetAutomatocTimeEnabled(YES);
```

If you want to know in which state these settings are you can use these functions

```
BOOL TMIsAutomaticTimeEnabled();
BOOL TMIsAutomaticTimeZoneEnabled();
```

3) Change current date and time

Declare these

```
struct timezone
{
    int tz_minutewest;
    int tz_dsttime;
};

void settimeofday(struct timeval*, struct timezone*);
```

This API is public in OS X so you can find documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/settimeofday.2.html

As an example we will set clock 10 minutes forward

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:600] timeIntervalSince1970];
tv.tv_usec = 0;

settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
```

4) Notify about date/time change

```
CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), CFSTR("SignificantTimeChangeNotification"), NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

Comment: Hi. I get the following error: "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements". So I guess I need a jailbroken device?

Comment: Yes. Furthemore, `settimeofday` can't be called from sandboxed app.

Comment: Hi creker, could you please explain how to link to CoreTime framework in Xcode?