# Appcelerator Make an app that changes phone's time

Tags: time, appcelerator

I want to make an app in Appcelerator that can change the time of your phone, but I dont know the code to let it change because I am new to Appcelerator.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're here to help you with issues you have. Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question.

Comment: You will likely need to drop-down to the native APIs, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278450/changing-iphones-date-and-time).

Comment: @Rene, can we really change the time of an iPhone programmatically as I think Titanium does not have any such API or even the native iOS SDK probably won't have?

Comment: I don't think native iOS even has support for it.

Comment: Yes, but I had seen yesterday a post of doing this in native iOS. But do not know why anyone will want to do this...or for what purpose

Answer (score 0):

If it’s possible in the underlying phone SDK (iOS I believe has a public API for this) then yes you could achieve this using the new Hyperloop module, currently in beta and released later this month — this would allow you access the underlying SDK directly via JS in your Ti SDK project.